# How to redirect the input and ignore the output using popen?

Tags: c++, popen

The files I am using look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char buffer[] = "file.txt\n";
    FILE *fp = popen("input.exe", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), fp);
    pclose(fp);
}
```

Which calls the compiled program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path;
    cout << "Enter path ";
    cin >> path;
    cout << "You entered " << path << endl;
}
```

The output I get from running the program is:

```
Enter path You entered file.txt
```

I am redirecting the input using popen, but how can I ignore the `cout << "Enter path";` as well?

Comment: You can't. The `popen` function doesn't redirect both `stdin` and `stdout`, only one of them. If you want that functionality you need to go a level down and do what `popen` does "behind the scenes" and call the system functions yourself. How to do that for your platform (Windows?) should be possible to find easily with a little searching.

Comment: You cannot selectively ignore some output from stdout/std::cout. Your best option is remove that line of code.

Comment: @RSahu I am trying to find a solution without editing that file as that is how I would like to use it in application.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using Windows. Could you give me a tip as to where to start on searching for that? Or if you think there is a better way to go about it?

Comment: An ugly hack would be to use `std::cerr` to say "Enter path". Since `popen` doesn't redirect `stderr`, you'll skip this.